# Bash tries to execute function definition

Tags: bash

I am learning some bash scripting, and i have stumbled upon an issue. I have the following code:

```
function confirm {
while true; do
  read -p "Do you wish to install this program?" response
     case $response in
        [Yy]* ) echo "will be installed"; break;;
        [Nn]* ) echo "will be skipped"; exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes(y) or no(n).";;
  esac
done
}
confirm
```

but when i run it, it executes, and also show an error.
test2.sh: 1: test2.sh: function: not found (script is called test2.sh)
Any ideas how to avoid this?

Comment: Are you sure you're running `bash`?  That error sounds like you might be running plain Bourne shell, where the function definition would be `confirm() {` since there's no `function` keyword.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Defining it as you said, confirm() {} solves the issue

Comment: Since you tagged this question `bash`, it might be better to make sure you're actually running `bash`; you will run into other surprises if you are programming for a different shell than the one you're running.  See my answer.

Comment: ...though it's also best to not be in a habit of using `function`, since it's nonportable and adds no benefit over the portable syntax.

Comment: ...btw, this is "before you ask" item #2 on the tag wiki (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `#!/usr/bin/env bash` at the top to make sure you're actually running the script with bash. Traditional `/bin/sh` didn't have a `function` keyword.